# Contar options de um select

Tags: jquery

Preciso contar as opções de um `select`. Se tiver apenas 1 opção, submeto o formulário. Como faço isso em jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Para simplesmente saber quantos elementos existem dentro de outro você pode tentar recuperá-los, algo assim:

```
let options = $("select option"); // options.length irá indicar qtd de elementos
```

**Exemplo**

```js
$("input").click(function() {
    let opts = $("select option");
    console.log(opts.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Contar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Com dois options, não submete**

```js
if($('#MeuSelect option').size()==1){
    $('#form-listar-imovel').submit();
};
console.log($('#MeuSelect option').size());
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <form id="form-listar-imovel" action="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered">
    
    <select  id="MeuSelect">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>1</option>
    </select>
    
    </form>
```

**Com um option, submete**

```js
if($('#MeuSelect option').size()==1){
    $('#form-listar-imovel').submit();
};
console.log($('#MeuSelect option').size());
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <form id="form-listar-imovel" action="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered">
    
    <select  id="MeuSelect">
        <option>1</option>
    </select>
    
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o childElementCount  do javascript exemplo...

```js
if(document.querySelector('select').childElementCount > 1)
console.log('mais de 1 > submit: ' + document.getElementById('form').submit);
```

```html
    <select>
      <option>teste</option>
      <option>teste</option>
    </select>

    <form action="https://www.google.com.br" id="form">
     
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui o que eu queria. Sou novo no jquery

```
 if ($('#municipio-index option').size() == 1){
                $('#form-listar-imovel').submit();

};
```

Obrigado a todos